# Android: “Constant expression required” error with R.id.navigation_bar_home in switch-case

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm running into a problem in my Android code. I'm trying to use `R.id.navigation_bar_home` in a `switch-case` statement, but I'm getting an error saying "Constant expression required". Here is the relevant code:

```java
binding.navigationBar.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.navigation_bar_home:
            break;
    }
    return true;
});
```

`R.id.navigation_bar_home` is defined in my XML resource file as follows:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_bar_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home"
        android:title="Home" />
</menu>
```

I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, and I also synced the project with the Gradle files, but the error persists. Can anyone help me understand what is causing this error and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I changed the switch case in if statement and it works, but i don't know why it works.